# Using data from one request for second url request in same script python

Tags: python, request

What I have so far is the first request gathering `Id's`. I would then like to use that return `draftgroupid` to insert into the second url request. Is it possible to send two requests in the same script, and if so how would I do a `for i in range(draftgroupid)` in the second url request?

```
import requests
import json

req1 = requests.get(url="https://www.draftkings.com/lobby/getcontests?sport=NHL")
req.raise_for_status()
data = req.json()

for i, contest in enumerate(data['DraftGroups']):
    draftgroupid = contest['DraftGroupId']
```

`Output of draftgroupid:
16901
16905
16902
16903`

```
req2 = requests.get(url="https://api.draftkings.com/draftgroups/v1/draftgroups/THEVALUEIWANTTOLOOPTHROUGH/draftables?format=json")
```

**EDIT**

```
import csv
import requests
import json

req = requests.get(url="https://www.draftkings.com/lobby/getcontests?sport=NHL")
req.raise_for_status()
data = req.json()

for i, contest in enumerate(data['DraftGroups']):
    draftgroupid = contest['DraftGroupId']
    req2 = requests.get(url="https://api.draftkings.com/draftgroups/v1/draftgroups/" + str(draftgroupid) + "/draftables?format=json")
    data2 = req2.json

    for i, player_info in enumerate(data2['draftables'][0]):
        date = player_info['competition']['startTime']
        print(date)
```

Running into a `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: yes, you can send even million requests if only server doesn't block your requests.

Comment: What do you mean by "insert into the second url request"?

Comment: first request gathers Id's and stores as `draftgroupid`. After `req2` under the `Output` is what i would like to run and loop through that Id's in the position of the url name `THEVALUEIWANTTOLOOPTHROUGH`

Comment: elements in request can be send in different way: as text in url, as header, as cookie, as form data in body, as json data in body. You have to read server documentation to see which method it expects.

Comment: url is normal string so you can use string.replace() or string formatting to create new url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, your problem is related to string manipulation rather than for the `request` library.

So basically,

```
import requests
import json

 req1 = requests.get(url="https://www.draftkings.com/lobby/getcontests?sport=NHL")
 req.raise_for_status()
 data = req.json()

 for i, contest in enumerate(data['DraftGroups']):
     draftgroupid = contest['DraftGroupId']
     requests.get(url="https://api.draftkings.com/draftgroups/v1/draftgroups/" + str(draftgroupid) + "/draftables?format=json")
```

should do the job.

More elegant ways to concatenate strings can be found at http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python

**Edit**

For example,

```
"some string " + str(123)
"some string %d" % 123
"some string %s" % 123
```

Will all give the same output. There are more ways to concatenate strings. You just need to choose the best fit based on the context.

Comment: `TypeError: must be str, not int`. Thanks for the quick response. I tried it out and got the typeerror

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson Edited the answer. Please accept the answer if it answers your question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the extra example. It helps to understand the language for a beginner!

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is happening in that large code block.  Edit your question to include the code and the full error message.

Comment: `data2 = req2.json` should be `data2 = req2.json()`.  You forgot the `()`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, contest in enumerate(data['DraftGroups']):
    draftgroupid = contest['DraftGroupId']
    req2 = requests.get(url="https://api.draftkings.com/draftgroups/v1/draftgroups/%d/draftables?format=json" % draftgroupid)
```

I assume you didn't actually mean `for i in range(draftgroupid)` as you stated in the question, because that would mean making 16901 requests, followed by 16905 requests (all of which except the last four would be duplicates of the first batch), followed by 16902 requests (of which all would be duplicates), etc.